# Windows Phone Contacts App - How to get kind of returned number?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, contacts

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app.  It is a contacts viewer to help people manage their contacts.  I want to display all contacts with all data values that exist... like name, phone, address, etc.

If you see when you edit a contact, you can add two phone numbers for a mobile phone, home phone and work phone.  When I list the values using [ContactPhone.Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactphone.kind), it just returns Mobile, Home or Work, without indicating if it's 1 or 2!

That's good, but how can I know if it is number 1 or number 2?

For example if a contact has mobile 1 and mobile 2 info entered, they both show up in an app as just Mobile.  If I have a contact that only has mobile 2 entered, when displayed in the app, the Contact Phone Kind just says Mobile...

Is there a way to know that it is really mobile 2?

.....

More Information After More Research:

To further extend this question, I added a sample contact using the standard People app, and added all phone numbers:

mobile, mobile 2, home, home 2, work, work 2, company, pager, home fax, work fax

When I check the contact phone kind for each number contained in contact's phones, I get:

Mobile, Mobile, Home, Home, Work, Work, Work, Other, Other, Other

I'm guessing there is no way to tell which number is of which kind...because the standard People app must keep track each of the numbers internally.

Can anyone explain this or offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that there's no way to do it.